# Flash syntax error

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm a newbie with flash, what I'm trying to do is make the background scroll with my mouse...but this is giving me a syntax error...where is the error coming from?

```
var movieWidth:Number = stage.stageWidth;

menuWidth = nav1.width;

nav2.x = nav1.x + menuWidth;

addEventListener("enterFrame",frame_handler);

function frame_handler(e:Event) {
var a:Number = mouseX;
var b:Number = movieWidth/2;
var c:Number = 20;
var pos:Number= 0-((a-b)/20);

nav1.x += pos;
nav2.x += pos;

if (nav1.x >= 0 && nav1.x <= menuWidth)
{ nav2.x = nav1.x – menuWidth }
else if (nav1.x <= movieWidthmenuWidth)
{ nav2.x = nav1.x + menuWidth }

if (nav2.x <=movieWidth-menuWidth) 
{ nav1.x = nav2.x + menuWidth } 
else if (nav2.x>=0) 
{ nav1.x = nav2.x- menuWidth }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting the error at compile time, or is it at run time? What does the error message say? Can you highlight the specific line? We can try to explain the error once we've seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this statement

```
{ nav2.x = nav1.x – menuWidth }
```

I think that your minus character is wrong one in this statement

```
wrong one (ASCII 8211)  –

correct one (ASCII 45) -
```

Please replace. Check other statements also.

See this : http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/characters/

Answer (score 0):

Is `menuWidth` ever declared? same for `nav1` and `nav2` - what is it?

Besides, you would be on the safe side, if you put a semicolon after a statement. It is not mandatory as per the compiler rules, but it may put you in a confusing situation, where you would misinterpret the code.

As an aside: unary `-` operator does the same as binary `-` operator when the first operand is 0. That is the expression:

```
0 - x
```

is equivalent to:

```
-x
```